# What do double underscores indicate?

Tags: python, django, name-mangling

In Python I know that double underscores preceding a name cause Python to prepend the `classname` to the `variable` name as in `_classname__variable` name (name mangling). So my question is this, in an Python/Django app I have been asked to modify, there are variable(?) names of the type `tr_rowid_debtor__de_listed_date__lte` . Is this three variables (`tr_rowid_debtor`, `de_listed_date` and `lte`) or is this some special construct for Python? It is occurring in a statement that builds a query string for Django ...

```
query = DeTransaction.objects.select_related().filter(
    tr_rowid_debtor__de_listed_date__lte=to_date,
    tr_rowid_debtor__de_rowid_client__cl_rowid=in_client
).values(
    'tr_rowid_debtor','tr_rowid_debtor__de_listed_date',
    'tr_payment_date','tr_account','tr_to_agency','tr_to_client'
)
```

Any advice here would be appreciated.

Comment: You should do the Django tutorial, where this construct (use to traverse model relationships) is explained.

Comment: As @DanielRoseman said; the condition is being made using a field of a related model. Also, I split the one liner into multiple lines for readability's sake.

Answer (score 12):

The double underscore notation is used by Django's ORM to indicate some sort of separation in a query. In the case of `tr_rowid_debtor__de_listed_date__lte`, three things are happening.

1. `tr_rowid_debtor` specifies the attribute on `DeTransaction`, which is a relationship based on what happens next
2. `de_listed_date` specifies the field of the related model to query against
3. `lte` says to perform the comparison using `<=` (less than or equal to)

It's worth a read of [Django's query docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/). The cover these in some detail.

As for whether or not this is special to Python, it is not. the `__` is assigned to a constant called [`LOOKUP_SEP`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/86f4459f9e3c035ec96578617605e93234bf2700/django/db/models/constants.py). The value is used with `str.split()` to generate the `WHERE` clause for queries.

Comment: Thanks to all for the answers, this will help. Reading Django query docs now. Is there a good recent book/ebook on Django/Python?